# How to show outlook add-in in the main pane instead of compose and read context

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

It's my first time developing add in for outlook, i'm tryng to do an add-in that interact with outlook calendar to find an appointment, but i can only show up the add-in when i create new appointment, is there any way to show it outside compose and read context? like viva insights do?
i found that this can be done with VSTO, but i need it to work also with web outlook and other os, if someone can help me to figure it out i will apreciate.

i tried to do it following the add-in doc

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview#extension-points

i can't find an extension point that fits my purpose.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you might be referring to [UI-less add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial#implement-a-ui-less-button).

Comment: thank you a lot, i tried it but is not what i'm tryng to do, mi goal is someting like the img, show my add-in always in the ribbon or only in calendar view if is it possibile

https://ibb.co/3T0gngz

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? If your add-in is not visible on the Toolbar, you can customize the toolbar and pin the add-in there.

Comment: sorry i'll try to explain it better, my add-in is visible but is clickable only in compose or read context, i would like to have it clickable in every context of outlook. 
Example: i open the main page of outlook and in the toolbar i would like to see my add in not disabled

Comment: I believe a pinnable task pane add-in fits your purpose. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane .

Comment: Add-ins are only valid in Mail/Calendar individual item context currently. Hence, if no item (email / event) is selected, addins do not show-up or work - it does not know in which context it is suppose to run. 

If your scenario requires it to run without email/event context, we suggest you to file a feature request here: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Add-ins are only valid in Mail/Calendar individual item context currently. Hence, if no item (email / event) is selected, addins do not show-up or work - it does not know in which context it is suppose to run.

If your scenario requires it to run without email/event context, we suggest you to file a feature request here: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions